# How to get out-of-sample predictions for specific subgroups, in Stata?

Tags: regression, stata, logistic-regression, predict, marginal-effects

I have a mixed effects logistic regression model:

```
quietly melogit y i.x1 i.x2 || x3:
```

Variable x1 is coded 0/1. I create the predicted probabilities for both values of x1:

```
margins x1
```

Then I obtain the predicted probabilities for each observation included in the model:

```
predict probhat if e(sample)
summarize probhat
```

To make out-of-sample predictions, I load my second dataset with the same variables:

```
use "C:\file path\newdata.dta", clear
```

Now I can get the predicted probabilities for each observation in the new dataset:

```
predict probhat_new
summarize probhat_new
```

My question is: How do I get what the 'margins' command created for the original dataset, but for the new dataset?

```
margins x1
```

Stata returns:

```
e(sample) does not identify the estimation sample
```

I also tried to recreate original output based on 'margins' by calculating the mean of probhat for each value of x1, hoping that I could use the same approach to get out-of-sample subgroup predicted probabilities:

```
summarize probhat if x1== 0, meanonly
scalar mean_probhat_x1_0 = r(mean)

gen mean_probhat=.
replace mean_probhat = mean_probhat_x1_0 if x1== 0
summarize mean_probhat
```

However, the mean based on this code is different from the mean for x1==0 based on the 'margins' command.

I also tried an alternative approach:

```
egen mean_probhat = mean(probhat), by(x1)
tab mean_probhat
```

But this also doesn't produce the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `estimates esample:` to reset the estimation sample; see `help estimates esample`. As the help file explains, you can easily amend the command to specify a subsample (e.g. those with non-missing values in specific variables) but here I'll just set the whole dataset as the estimation sample.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
webuse bangladesh, clear
qui: melogit c_use i.urban age i.children || district:
margins urban

webuse bangladesh, clear    // clears the estimation sample: e(sample) == 0 for all obs
estimates esample:    // resets estimation sample: e(sample) == 1 for all obs
margins urban
```